# Visual C++ cannot open include file error, fixes with a second consecutive build

Tags: include, visual-c++-2008

I am running into this issue, which, although not a show-stopper is becoming increasingly annoying.

I have a project where a rebuild or a build after some changes will result in the C1083 error:

> fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'Filename.h' no such file or directory

If I build again, the issue goes away! (I have checked the include directories, they are good). A rebuild always fails with this error and must be followed by a normal build to fix the issue.

Has anybody run into this issue? Any guesses as to what may be the cause of the problem?

Comment: Is that header file generated by MIDL? If that's the case, it might be a dependency problem: the project depending on `Filename.h` is built before the one generating it.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: No, that is not the case (today is the first time I heard of MIDL :)

Comment: Are you using any code generator?

Comment: @Flot2011: Not that I know of... the project was created via Visual Studio's project wizard (empty project, I did all the includes manually). I have created countless projects, this is the first project I am encountering this on (it is a big project, re-creating it will take quite a bit of time - so I thought this may be a known problem with a solution)

Comment: Another explanation would be that a post-build event is copying the header file to some location, and your project is referring (directly or indirectly) to this location from its `#include` directives. So, if your project is built before the one copying the file, it will fail. However, for that behavior to persist for several builds, the header file would have to be removed in a pre-build event... Anyway, it would be interesting to know from where the failing project tries to fetch the header file.